# Where can I spend these Lost Ark token currencies?

Tags: lost-ark

I have been amassing these two token currencies for all of my playthrough and I still have no idea where to spend them.

[image: Currency Inventory > Token Items > Sylmael Bloodstone and Providence Stone]

Where can I spend my Sylmael Bloodstone and Providence Stones?

Comment: Providence stones are used to buy Rapport items at various exchanges NPCs, but i dont know about bloodstones.

Comment: Bloodstone can be used to buy items at Sylmael Bloodstone Exchange. They can be found in cities like Origins of Stern in Arthetine or Luterra Castle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providence Stones can be exchanged with various NPCs, in many major cities such as Luterra Castle the generic Rapport Exchange NPC can be depicted by a pink exchange icon on the map as opposed to the grey ones that most other exchange NPCs have. E.g [Nada in Luterra Castle](https://lostarkcodex.com/us/npc/81107/) - They will trade you Rapport Items for your Providence Stones.

There are some outliers that will also exchange for your Stones, but ultimately they're all tied to Rapport based items. E.g '[Lobster Dish](https://www.invenglobal.com/lostark/item/70500045/lobster-dish)' in Peyto and '[Perfect Log](https://lostarkcodex.com/us/item/70503003/)'.

Bloodstones can be exchanged at any [Slymael Bloodstone Exchange](https://thegamescabin.com/sylmael-bloodstone-lost-ark-database/). They're found in a few major cities ([Tiella](https://lostarkcodex.com/us/npc/25316/), [Anais](https://lostarkcodex.com/us/npc/25317/), [Le'verille](https://lostarkcodex.com/us/npc/25318/), [Avril](https://lostarkcodex.com/us/npc/25319/)).

You can exchange the stones for a variety of items, most notably honing materials and entrance tickets for certain activities. Most of these have both item level limitations and weekly limitations. (You can only get so many of each honing material per week - reset is on Thursday like many other weekly resets).